# Unselect checkbox at click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, unselect

I set up a basic shopping cart where you have to put goods into a green box to order them. When you click on the item icon, it correctly checks the associated checkbox. Unfortunately, when you click again on it, it doesn't uncheck.

I've tried **`$(elem).prop('checked', false);** but it doesn't work. Do you have any other idea please?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbsoLp0u/8/ (I've let the checkbox displayed on to let you see the bug).

Code:

**html**

```
<div id="selected"></div>

    <div id="nonSelected">

      <label for="blackjack"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/blackjack.gif' data-unchecked='img/blackjack.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="blackjack" type="checkbox" value="Blackjack" name="game[]">    

      <label for="chuckaluck"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/AvPEx4i.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/chuckaluck.gif' data-unchecked='img/chuckaluck.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="chuckaluck" type="checkbox" value="Chuck a Luck" name="game[]">

      <label for="roulette"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/tBEisp3.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/roulette.gif' data-unchecked='img/roulette.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="roulette" type="checkbox" value="Roulette" name="game[]">

      <label for="stud"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/Oigq8QI.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/stud.gif' data-unchecked='img/stud.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="stud" type="checkbox" value="Stud Poker" name="game[]">

      <label for="holdem"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/Oc52z68.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/holdem.gif' data-unchecked='img/holdem.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="holdem" type="checkbox" value="Holdem Poker" name="game[]">

      <label for="boule"><img onclick="moveButton(this)" src="http://i.imgur.com/XFsfu7S.jpg" alt="" data-checked='img/boule.gif' data-unchecked='img/boule.jpg'></label>
      <INPUT id="boule" type="checkbox" value="La Boule" name="game[]">

  </div>
```

**js**

```
function moveButton(elem){
    if( $(elem).closest("div").attr("id") == "nonSelected" ){
        $(elem).prependTo('#selected');
    }
    else{
        $(elem).prependTo('#nonSelected');
    }
}
```

**css**

```
#selected{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #339933;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

img{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are moving to the `selected` container, the `label` is not moved which is having the `for` attribute which decides which `checkbox` to check so

```
function moveButton(elem){
    var $elem = $(elem).parent();
    if( $elem.closest("div").attr("id") == "nonSelected" ){
        $elem.prependTo('#selected');
    }
    else{
        $elem.insertBefore('#'+$elem.attr('for'));
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9hpp81qL/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the checkbox is checked on click, is because the image is inside the label-tag. The reason why it is not unchecked on second click, is because at that time it is not in the label tag. There are several ways to solve this, for example instead of moving the image, you could move the label inside the dom:

```
function moveButton(elem){
    if( $(elem).closest("div").attr("id") == "nonSelected" ){
        $(elem).parent('label').prependTo('#selected');
    }
    else{
        $(elem).parent('label').prependTo('#nonSelected');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbsoLp0u/10/